# How to calculate max using postgres dialect in sqlalchemy hybrid function

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've defined a hybrid property:

```
@hybrid_property
def result(self):
    return max(0, self.impact - self.protection)

@result.expression
def result(cls):
    return func.max(0, cls.impact - cls.protection)
```

However the Postgres `max` function only operates on columns, unlike e.g. sqlite so the expression won't work. Is there something I could use in the [Column elements or expressions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html), or some other way I can clamp my value to a lower bound of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the python function named 'max', not the PostgreSQL function.

If this somehow is postgresql, then `max` is for aggregates over rows.  `greatest` is for multiple-arguments.

```
greatest(thing1,thing2)
```

Comment: `func` is for SQL expressions, so I _was_ calling postgres `max`, which, as you say, is for aggregates only. `greatest` is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!